# swift-lldb compilation fails with c++11 error

Tags: swift, cmake, clang, ubuntu-14.04, lldb

I am trying to compile `swift-lldb` on `Ubuntu 14.04` (following instructions from https://github.com/apple/swift-lldb). I have the following dependencies installed:

1. `Clang-3.5`
2. `Cmake version 3.5.2`
3. `Python version 2.7.6`

On running the build script step which is `lldb/scripts/build-swift-cmake.py --test`, I am seeing the following error:

```
CMake Warning at cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:185 (message):
  -fPIC is not supported.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:216 (add_flag_or_print_warning)
  CMakeLists.txt:616 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:429 (message):
  LLVM requires C++11 support but the '-std=c++11' flag isn't supported.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:616 (include)
```

I have defined environment variables `CC` and `CXX` to point to the `clang` C and C++ compilers.

```
root:/myswift# echo $CC
/usr/bin/clang
root:/myswift# echo $CXX
/usr/bin/clang++
```

I also found in the `clang` documentation that `c++11` is supported by `clang-3.5`. Not sure what I am missing here. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

`clang-4.0` mentioned as part of the installation should support the `-std=c++11` flag (just tested clang-4.0.1). However, upgrading to `clang-6.0` seems to solve this build process error.

Running `cmake` directly in the automatically created build directory (by the swift build scripts) could be used to investigate the build failure in more detail. To specify compilers here, rather than setting `CC` and `CXX` environment variables (which works well for GNU configure scripts), compilers can be set for `cmake` via

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ path_to_src_or_build_directory
```

An existing `CMakeCache.txt` might have to be removed, so that the above parameters are honored.

A problem with `clang++` installations that I have observed is that `clang++` cannot find `C++ headers` (i.e. if `C++` headers are in non-standard locations other than `/usr/include`, unlikely in the case of Ubuntu though). In case `/usr/bin/clang++` cannot compile a simple program like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

not being able to find the `iostream` include file, it might help to set `--gcc-toolchain=/pathtoaworkinggcc`, where `pathtoaworkinggcc` should include `include`, `lib`, `bin`, etc. of a working `C++` compiler (possibly `g++` in the case of a Ubuntu installation).

Comment: From the logs, it looks like those cmake flags are already being passed to the cmake command. Here is a part of the command - `env /usr/local/bin/cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH=/usr/bin/clang++`

Comment: Just verified that my `clang++` is able to compile a `C++` program

Comment: I see: the `swift` build process is taking care of setting the `cmake` flags already. I have edited my answer with another `clang++` problem that I have come across.

Comment: The only suggestion I have left is to compile a newer `clang` first: I have compiled `swift` itself on an older custom Linux installation by compiling `clang-6.0` first; the underlying `gcc`/`g++` used as the `gcc-toolchain` was version `6.4.0`.

Comment: I upgraded my ubuntu version to 18.04. On installing `clang` as a dependency, `clang-6.0` was installed by default. I don't see the `c++11` error anymore with this setup. Looks like upgrading the clang version would've fixed things on ubuntu 14.04 as well.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the anecdotal evidence we have of `clang-6.0` being able to compile `swift` or `swift-lldb`.